# How to configure index pattern in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have connected Kibana to my ES instance.

cat/indices returns:

```
yellow open .kibana 1 1      1 0 3.1kb 3.1kb 
yellow open tests   5 1 413042 0 3.4gb 3.4gb
```

However I get the following on the kibana configuration screen. What am I missing?

[image: Kibana screenshot]

Update:

[image]

My sample document looks like this

```
    "_index": "tests",
    "_type": "test7",
    "_id": "AVGlIKIM1CQ8BZRgLZVg",
    "_score": 1.7840601,
    "_source": {
       "severity": "ERROR",
       "code": "CODE,
       "message": "MESSAGE",
       "environment": "TEST",
       "error_uuid": "cbe99080-0bf3-495c-a417-77384ba0fd39",
       "correlation_id": "cf5a1fd5-4fd2-40bb-9cdf-405b91dcbd6f",
       "timestamp": "2015-11-20 15:24:39.831"
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Disable the option `Use event times to create index names` and put the index name instead of the pattern (`tests`).

The option you are trying to use is used when you have index names based on timestamp (imagine you create a new index per day with `tests-2015.12.01`, `tests-2015.12.02`...). It's quite clear if you read the message when you enable that option:

> Patterns allow you to define dynamic index names. Static text in an index name is denoted using brackets. Example: [logstash-]YYYY.MM.DD. Please note that weeks are setup to use ISO weeks which start on Monday

**EDIT:** The problem with an empty dropdown in the time-field name is because you don't have any field with date type in the mapping of your index. You can actually check if you do `GET /<index-name>/_mapping?pretty`, that the `timestamp` is a "string" type and not "date". This happens because the format didn't match the [regex for the date detection](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html#date-detection) (`yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss Z||yyyy/MM/dd Z`). To solve this:

- You can change the format of the timestamp you are inserting to match the default regex.
- You can modify the `dynamic_date_format` property and put a regex that matches the current format of your timestamp.
- You can set an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) and set the type "date" for the "timestamp" field.

In any of the cases, you would need to delete the index and create a new one or reindex the data.

Comment: When I do that I am suppose to pick a Time-field name, but the drop box is empty. I've uploaded another image.

Comment: @freefall The problem is a different one then, I updated my answer.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot! One more question. Some of my date is written in word1-word2-word3 form. Does elasticsearch by default inteprets - as "splitter" for strings fields? I see that some of my have been catogorized in multiple "buckets"

Comment: If you do `curl -XGET localhost:9200_analyze?text="word1-word2-word3"` you can see how ES process your data. By default, it uses the [standard tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/analysis-standard-tokenizer.html) that will split everything separated by dashes into tokens. @freefall

Comment: I am not sure if I should ask another question hence I am writing here. Can I configure standard tokenizer to ignore dashes? A little bit of googling shows that to employ other toknizer I have to change analyzer. This seems to be an overkill for the purpose.

Comment: @freefall AFAIK no, but changing the analyzer is no overkill in my opinion, it's something that needs to be done depending on your needs (for example, I use a custom analyzer with the whitespace tokenizer).